# How to get Firebase serverTime?

Tags: java, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For android:
We can get serverTime by:

```
Timestamp.now().getSeconds();
```

Then for iOS we can get serverTime by:

```
Timestamp.init().seconds
```

**My problem:** 
Timestamp.now().getSeconds(); is 13 characters long, Timestamp.init().seconds is only 10 characters long.

Is there a way to get the 13 characters serverTime on xCode?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Swift and Java.

Answer (score 2):

Those lines of code are not getting server time at all.  They're getting local time on the device, in the form of a Timestamp object, converted to seconds.  There's no API to get server time directly and accurately.

The number of seconds is a number.  It's not measured in "number of characters" like a string.  I suggest reading the [API documentation for Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp) to better understand the meaning of the methods you're calling, and choose the one that meets your specific needs.  You might have to do some conversions to get what you want, so be clear to understand what you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.

Swift has:

```
ServerValue.timestamp()
```

Just didn't think of it, for some reason. Only needed it to be written to the server.